# What is this kanji? 「兵」

Tags: kanji, writing-identification

I am having difficulty locating this kanji. My guess is the radical is cliff "厂" with 7 strokes. However, my dictionary fails me. The closest I got is 后.

[image]

Comment: On it's own pronounced `つわもの` or `いくさ`, although I'm guessing these are a lot less frequent than just `へい`.

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful, but as a Korean speaker, I recognize the kanji—it's the character for "soldier," commonly found written on janggi (Korean chess) pieces to indicate a pawn. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janggi#Soldiers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's 兵 as in 兵士. Its radical is 八 (はち(がしら)） and apparently *not* 斤 （おの(づくり)） or 厂 (がんだれ). 7 strokes.

http://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%85%B5

Comment: Wow, never would have guessed that as the radical.

Comment: When you can't find it under one radical it's always best to check the others just to be sure!

Comment: Not all radicals are obvious, unfortunately.  This one is particularly amusing, though, as かしら in 八頭【はちがしら】 literally means "head", and yet it's acting as feet here.